# Run LDA algorithm on Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, lda

I use spark 2.0.0 and I'd like to train a LDA model to Tweets dataset, when I try to execute

```
val ldaModel = new LDA().setK(3).run(corpus)
```

I get this error

```
error: reference to LDA is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA and import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA
```

Could someone please help me ? 
Thanks !

Comment: can you please upload code

Comment: you imported the LDA twice 
see the import you will find 
 import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA  
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have both of the following import statements:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA
```

You would need to remove one of them.

If you are using Spark ML (data frame based API), the proper syntax would be:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA

/*feature extraction step*/

val lda = new LDA().setK(3)
val model = lda.fit(corpus)
```

if you are using RDD-based API then you would have to write:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA

/*feature extraction step*/

val lda = new LDA().setK(3)
val model = lda.run(corpus)
```